# Orchard's Lost Password returning 302 and redirecting

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

We are experiencing some odd behaviour when attempting to POST to the Lost Password action on the Account Controller in Orchard.Users.

The important details

- We are not directly using Orchard source code, we are using a compiled re-distributable and building modules that are deployed to the redist host, so direct debugging is a challenge.
- We have tried this with the vanilla Orchard 1.8.1 (the version of our redist) so we can all but eliminate any of our module's code.
- When POSTing the form we get back a *302 Moved* response with the *Location Header* set to /. This then does end up to root rather than to the Success page or back to the Enter New Details password. The user's password is not successfully changed.
- Looking at the Account Controller in source shows that the only result that expressly returns the root is when the the call *IUserService.ValidateLostPassword(nonce)* fails and the *return Redirect("~/");* is called.
- Seeing as direct debugging is a little complex, we acquired a copy of the Controller from source and moved the action code and all related service call logic into an Orchard command for testing. This has succeeded in changing a user's password. and returning without error, using the NOnce captured from the reset email.

So we suspect this may be a bug with Orchard itself though more likely to be with our instance and it's configuration seeing as "Cannot change password" is a pretty expansive issue.

Anyone have any advice to offer? Known bugs that may apply?

**Update 1:**

Thank you Bertrand. We have not tried it with Orchard 1.9 yet but did manage to get a completely clean 1.8 (as this is the version we are currently running out in the wild from with one of our repos. P.S. Are you aware that your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard) braches go 1.4.x, 1.5.x, 1.9.x? No 1.8.x available. Anyway.) and this worked. The short version: we played around with what could be different and we got it down to it works when our theme is off and doesn't when it on.

A little digging showed that our FE guys has overwritten the Lost Password view to match our business look. Here is what I found:

In the default Orchard view the form is started using:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) {
```

and ends up looking like

```
<form action="/OrchardLocal/Users/Account/LostPassword?nonce=Vc7ABvKcwfMO0jrRkJFxiBWoJzbdGAqQ7bbEgGySqlyAAKnHPTIkyhzG8nn%2FXJsqKkh6e9sreTnHx223BKFOs17gY%2FDWMggtCZw%2BSfz194Mviua5smhl5d%2FnACXCI%2BrdQaGcJj%2BjvoFE7m2OIiaX8w%3D%3D" method="post">
```

all fine and dandy. I presume that because the nonce came in as a query param on the get, it is persisted to the post through inference in calling the default Begin Form without any additional settings.

However, our override currently uses:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost(Url.Action("LostPassword"), FormMethod.Post, new{ @class="form-lost-password"} ) ) {
```

Here we specify some additional class for the needs of our theme and on the page we get:

```
<form action="/Users/Account/LostPassword" class="form-lost-password" method="post">
```

The nonce has disappered (or rather has not been added at all since we are specifying an particular route). So the ready solution is the add the nonce on using the

```
Action(String, String, Object)
```

form of Url.Action() to specify it as a route value.

However, the nonce is not passed through as either a member on the Model nor through the ViewBag (like the minimum password length is).

I found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116542/reset-password-with-orchard-not-updating) previous question from the time of Orchard 1.6/1.7 which suggests updating the controller to add the nonce to the Viewbag but we are using a pre-compiled re-dist of Orchard so this is less than ideal for our needs.

I will be other ways of writing that form using what we have available to us without updating the Controller but is there any plan to make the nonce available to this view for use?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce with the source code? With a more recent version? Is SSL on?

Comment: Update 1 added to original question

Comment: There is no 1.8.x branch because there is no ongoing development of new versions under 1.8. 1.4.x and 1.5.x should not exist.

Comment: Did you try to add the nonce parameter to your action parameters, getting its value from Request?

Comment: No, as we are not using a source version of Orchard but a pre-compiled redist. We are trying to avoid any customizations to the Orchard code-base and just work with the vanilla releases so that we don't get tied to re-integrating with each new release. Particularly with 1.9 having recently come out. We could take it from the HttpContext but that seems very heavy handed to us.
Is there are particular reason that the NOnce isn't made available to the LostPassword form? It's in the query parameter so it don't see it needing to be hidden or anything.

Comment: Using the source code is not about making modifications to the core (although you are encouraged to do that if they are legitimate changes and you contribute them), it's about being able to debug with the full context, being able to study good practices, etc.
I was trying to give you a workaround, since you said you didn't have the source and didn't want to touch it. If you don't want to use that workaround, I think your only other option is to get the source code and fix it, or to file a bug and wait for someone to fix it.